# longtable package: Stretch height of last row on page

Tags: spacing, page-breaking, longtable

Consider the following code

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
    \begin{longtable}{|p{5cm}|}
        \hline
        \lipsum[5] \\\hline
        \lipsum[7] \\\hline
        \lipsum[1] \\\hline
        \lipsum[1-2] \\\hline
        \lipsum[5]\\\hline %no stretching here
    \end{longtable}
    some text below the table
\end{document}
```

which will lead to the result (minimal zoom level).

[image: screenshot]

As you can see the space between the lower border of the column and the lower page border differs for each page (especially on the 2nd one), which doesn't look good for me.

What I want is that each time a page break occurs the height of the last row is extended (stretched), so the distance from the lower line of the table to the bottom of the page is equal on each page. This should not occur for the last row of the table, because it will be embedded in other content. In the MWE I provided the last page therefore should just look as it does right now without any modification.

Do you have any idea how this can be achieved?

[Edit]

A fake screenshot of how the example would look like

[image]

Comment: A single cell will never be broken across pages.

Comment: It would be hard to do really. longtable uses a standard tex page breaking output routine which means that all the page content is set _before_ any decisions about page breaking are made.

Comment: @egreg I don't want to break single cells. The page breaking behaviour should stay the same, all I want is that after each page break: (1) the distance from the last position / the lower table limit on the last page to the lower page border is calculated and (2) the height of the last row is expanded by the distance from (1)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I don't know how this routines work internally, but would it be possible to output the table at first, calculate the distances and then recreate the table by using the calculated distances?

Comment: anything is possible, but it would require rewriting the package, not just a couple of lines of code in an answer here.

Comment: Well, as @DavidCarlisle (the package author btw) points out, this appears to be doable, but it's more a feature request than a question suitable for the site, because it can't really get an answer. However, it's IMHO not a bad question, so you still get +1 from me.

Comment: If you only need the lines always at the same location: draw them outside of longtable e.g. through the pagestyle. But imho you should also consider to use some other environment like a list where you can have page breaks inside the running text.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle what would you propose where to start if I wanted to modify your package that way? Is there any documentation about the tex page breaking routine you mentioned above (and how to extend or replace it)?

Comment: longtable really isn't the place to start (you'd have to rewrite all of it) it might be easier with xtab/superab as they set each page as a separate tabular (so you have access to the last row on each page as a macro rather than as an already typeset box) but if it is really a 1 or 2 column table then 99 times out of 100 it would be better set as a list (even if the layout is similar it is much easier to control list layout)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

semi-automatic method, using the `\pdfsavepos` extension to work out where the text ends then constructing a suitable length to use with `\\[something]` to extend the row.  I have not here tried to automatically determine the rows where the page breaks, so at the end of edits just change `\\` to `\zz{AomeUniqueLabel}`  You can see the lengths it is making in the aux file and adjust the `-150pt` to adjust exactly where the table ends. if you edit the document, delete the `aux` file or it will re-use spurious values. It takes a couple of runs always to use `\pdfavepos` values.

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\makeatletter
\def\zz#1{%
\pdfsavepos\write\@auxout{%
\gdef\expandafter\string\csname zz@#1\endcsname{%
 \string\\[\the\dimexpr\the\pdflastypos sp -150pt\relax]}}%
\expandafter\ifx\csname zz@#1\endcsname\relax
\expandafter\\%
\else
\csname zz@#1\expandafter\endcsname
\fi}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
    \begin{longtable}{|p{5cm}|}
        \hline
        \lipsum[5] \\\hline
        \lipsum[7] \zz{a}\hline
        \lipsum[1] \zz{b}\hline
        \lipsum[1-2] \zz{c}\hline
        \lipsum[5]\\\hline %no stretching here
    \end{longtable}
    some text below the table
\end{document}
```