# longtable package: Stretch height of last row on page "RTL document"

Tags: longtable, right-to-left, bidi

I took a look at this nice answer [longtable package: Stretch height of last row on page](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/280366/54817) and I need to apply this answer in my arabic document (right to left document).

The problem that I can not get the same output in RTL context (the table is not stretched)

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[showframe,margin=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{bidi}
\setmainfont[Script=Arabic]{Amiri}

\makeatletter
\def\zz#1{%
\pdfsavepos\write\@auxout{%
\gdef\expandafter\string\csname zz@#1\endcsname{%
 \string\\[\the\dimexpr\the\pdflastypos sp -80pt\relax]}}%
\expandafter\ifx\csname zz@#1\endcsname\relax
\expandafter\\%
\else
\csname zz@#1\expandafter\endcsname
\fi}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

%\setRTL

\begin{longtable}{|p{5cm}|}
\hline
a  \zz{c} \hline
\end{longtable}

\end{document}
```

**RTL context**

[image]

**LTR context**

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Interesting, seems you need to put `\pdfsavepos` after the `\write` not before it (in input file order)

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[showframe,margin=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{bidi}
\setmainfont[Script=Arabic]{FreeSerif}

\makeatletter
\def\zz#1{%
\write\@auxout{%
\gdef\expandafter\string\csname zz@#1\endcsname{%
 \string\\[\the\dimexpr\the\pdflastypos sp -80pt\relax]}}\pdfsavepos%
\expandafter\ifx\csname zz@#1\endcsname\relax
\expandafter\\%
\else
\csname zz@#1\expandafter\endcsname
\fi}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\setRTL

\begin{longtable}{|p{5cm}|}
\hline
a  \zz{c} \hline
\end{longtable}

\end{document}
```

Comment: How can I redefine the '\zz' without argument and it create for every call  `\zz@a` , `\zz@b` , `\zz@c` ,..... automatically.

Comment: @SalimBou quite possibly something like `\newcount\zzcount  \def\zzz{\global\advance\zzcount 1 \expandafter\zz\expandafter{\romannumeral\zzcount}`  (untested:-)  then use `\zzz`